# Unstable WIFI since Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS update

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel

I recently updated Ubuntu from 20.04.1 LTS to **22.04.1 LTS** and since I experience very unstable wifi connection on my Lenovo T460 with a wireless adapter **Intel Wireless 8260**

I have also I have a Windows 10 dual boot. fast startup is disabled.

Sometime when I startup Ubuntu, no wifi adapter is found at all. A few restarts could make it available again, with **kernel 5.15.0.50** or using the previous available kernel version 5.15.0-46-generic
Now it is never available.

**Additional info**

Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev ff)
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

`sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep -i version` 
`Version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.5`

sudo modprobe iwlwifi: Displays nothing

sudo dmesg | grep iwl: Displays nothing

dkms status: Displays nothing

I have tried below, as suggested in a similar issue, but it did not help

`sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak`

Remaining pnvm files below as been also moved to .bak files
`ls /usr/lib/firmware | grep -i pnvm`
`iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm`
`iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm`

Any help is welcome as I am not familiar at all with Linux driver issues

Thanks

Comment: Fast Boot, a firmware (UEFI feature, is NOT the problem. Fast Startup, a Windows feature can be. When dual-booting with Windows disabling it is a must.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I mean Windows fast startup. It is disabled yes. Qurestion edited

Comment: So driver file is iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode and is well present in firmware folder. 
But what are pnvm files?

Comment: Tried to check Wifi from Windows and now not available also from there. Bluetoth also unavailable from Ubuntu now.
Maybe the Wireless card is dead? How can I ensure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems it was an **hardware issue.**

After changing adapter Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 by a brand new one (Intel Corporation Wireless 9260), Wifi and Bluetooth are now back to normal without any other config change